# How can I create a tridimensional map in python?

Tags: python, matrix

I need to create a tridimensional map. I would create an x axis with values between 0 and 255 with step 0.5. The same thing with the y axis.
And then I would assign a value for each coordinate (for example at the point (10.5,10)).

Matrix is not the solution because I can't decide values in the x and y axes.

Can you help me?

EDIT: I try to explain better the question. This is a piece of my code:

```
img = cv2.imread('Lena256.bmp',0)
M = cv2.getRotationMatrix2D((cols/2,rows/2),angle,1)
img_rotate = cv2.warpAffine(img,M,(cols,rows))
```

Then I locate some point in the img_rotate: for example p=(10,10). I want to map "p" to the corresponding point in the original image. To do that I have written this code:

```
T = np.zeros((rows,cols))
T[10][10] = 1
M_INV = cv2.getRotationMatrix2D((cols/2,rows/2),-angle,1)
T = cv2.warpAffine(T,M_INV,(cols,rows))
```

In this way it works. But if I locate a point with no integer coordinates (in the img_rotate), for example (10.5,10), I should to create a matrix T with double dimensions where I could assign values 0, 0.5, 1, ecc in order to identify point (10.5,10). And then I could apply the inverse rotation.

I hope to be enough clear

Comment: can you give an example ?

Comment: can explain what you are trying to achieve? you have collection of points in 3-d space, denoted by tri-element tuples (x, y, z). Why do you need a map and what exactly do you mean by 'map'?

Comment: So, you are basically looking for a two-dimensional array with non-integer indices? Maybe you should just use a dict mapping tuples to values? Or scale the indices to integers.

Comment: I neet to rotate this tridimensional object. This is the problem

Answer (score 0):

You could use a dictionary:

```
d = {
    (10.5, 10): 23,
    (0,0): 42,
    (-100,999): 15,
    #etc
}
```

Then you can access the value at some coordinates (x,y) by doing `d[x,y]`. (or `d.get((x,y), default_value_goes_here)` if you're not sure whether that coordinate exists in the collection yet)

Answer (score 0):

you can use `np.meshgrid` for that

```py
import numpy as np

x_ = np.linspace(0., .5, 255)
y_ = np.linspace(1., .5, 255)
# You can make what you want in z ex:
z_ = np.linspace(3., 4., 30)

x, y, z = np.meshgrid(x_, y_, z_, indexing='ij')
```

Comment: I need to rotate the map (z in your case). This is the problem.

Comment: what do you mean by 'rotate'? isn't the transpose of z?

Comment: I need to consider my object as a matrix because I have to rotate it. The only difference betwwen matrices is that I need to assign values in the x and y directions.